# Opera mini doesn't support line-height

Tags: css, opera-mini

I've designed a website. However, line-height is not working in Opera Mini.

```
.lbl-name {
    height: 30px;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you really want to support Opera mini?

Comment: So who exactly supports Opera Mini now a days? http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/#basic-html-css

Comment: you also have other options like padding, font-size as well

Comment: And this article can maybe help you: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/

Comment: ty for all comments,
i will try "display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"

Comment: Just as a quick note for viewers of this question. One solution I was directed to by an Opera PM, is to use !important to force the `line-height` behavior for the time being.

Answer (score 5):

`Opera Mini` miss all `line-height`'s values and render all with `line-height: normal`.
I can't find proof any link, but on my developing experience(5 years support mobile sites, and for opera mini too) this is true.

**EDIT (add proof link):**

Opera Mini [use system fonts](http://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/2inpk0/opera_mini_font_data_calculation_problem/) for render texts, because a lot of devices can't render none-system fonts. So it do not apply `font-size`/`line-height` CSS properties.

Comment: Which is a very positive behaviour, otherwise the few pixels available on smaller screen phones would be wasted with excessive line-heights. To properly separate items, use padding instead.

Comment: Here you go . https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/#basic-html-css

Answer (score 0):

Use these definitions:

```
display: table; 
vertical-align: middle; 
height:50px;
```

For child tag:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue